# Core Data - NSPredicate to filter to-many relationship

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have 2 entities, Task and List. Each task has a to-one relationship to a List object called "list", and there is an inverse relationship with List, which has a to-many relationship with Task called "tasks".

I'm trying to use a fetch request with an NSPredicate to get all the Task objects that belong to a specified List:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"list=%@", theList];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

(where "theParent" is a reference to a List object). However this returns no fetched objects. If I take out the predicate, then the objects are returned (so I do know they exist, and by NSLogging `theList` I know it has Task objects associated with it).

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could it be a simple typo in your predicate?

You have "list=%@" when I assume what you really want is "list==%@"

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"list == %@", theList];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: kharrison and/or @sza: Can you clarify what you mean? [The NSPredicate documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215832) claims that `=` and `==` are 100% equivalent when used in predicate format strings. Is there an undocumented difference?